# ClassModule BeforeClose

Tags: excel, class, vba

I had a problem that I found the answer for, but it says "This code needs to be posted in a class module and an instance of the class needs to be created before it will work".
I am very familiar with "Modules" but never used Class Modules before, and can't seem to be able to figure out how to get this thing to run. Below is the code I'm using, and some of my random attempts to get it to run. There is this (A) and (WorkbookBeforeClose), and in "ThisWorkbook" another (BeforeClose), it's confusing me.

Usage of the code; I have a userform that when displayed, hides the window/application based on whether other Workbooks are open, this code is to resolve when closing other books both try to close.

Your help is very much appreciated

Code:

```
Public WithEvents A As Excel.Application

Private Sub A_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim VIS As Boolean, myAW As Workbook

If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then 'if there is more than one workbook open...
    If Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False Then 'and if Client is invisible...
        If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then 'and if the workbook being closed is the Client.
            Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
        Else 'more than one wb open, Client is invisible, and the workbook being closed is NOT the Client.
            Set myAW = ActiveWorkbook
            Cancel = True
            Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            myAW.Close
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            If ServiceEntry.ExcelB.Tag = "False" Then 'a tag on the button on the UserForm to store whether the workbook should be hidden or not
                If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
                    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
                Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        'more than one workbook open and the Client is visible and the workbook being closed is NOT the Client

        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual code. Usage of code does not serve the desired purpose. This community is to help you in overcoming problems faced in execution of code. So you have to mention what problem has been encountered while executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

To create an object, you only have to do :

```
Dim C As Class1 'where Class1 is your module class name
Set C = New Class1
```

You can do this in the initialization of your userForm :

```
Private Sub userForm_Initialize()
    Dim C As Class1
    Set C = New Class1
End Sub
```